# If a column is not null then convert into a row for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot, union-all

I have a table like below where I looking to transpose col4 col5 and col6 into rows but in a specific pattern that I listed below

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |  | 500 | 200 |
| w | x | y | 1000 | 300 |  |
| z | g | h | 200 |  | 600 |

I want to convert it to the following

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |  | 500 |  |
| a | b | c |  |  | 200 |
| w | x | y | 1000 |  |  |
| w | x | y |  | 300 |  |
| z | g | h | 200 |  |  |
| z | g | h |  |  | 600 |

I am trying this with unpivot but unable to get the desired result

Basically, if the null value is found in one of the columns for instance first record in col4 then the SQL query should ignore col4 which has the null value but transpose a b c col5 (500) into a row plus a b c col6 (200) into another row

Comment: Show us the query you are trying.

Comment: Please DO NOT use images for data, it was perfect as it was as formatted text.

Comment: Please do not use images of tables. We recently have added a table markdown and it helps us if you use it as we can quite easily see and extract the data we need. Please see: [Uploading images of tables considered harmful?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403699/12672179)

Comment: What does "first record" mean? _Rows_ in a table have no order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CROSS APPLY` combined with `UNION ALL` is very useful here:

```sql
SELECT
    t.col1, t.col2, t.col3,
    v.*
FROM table t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT col4, NULL, NULL
    WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, col5, NULL
    WHERE col5 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, col6
    WHERE col6 IS NOT NULL
) v
```

If you have many columns this gets tedious. Futhermore, this type of table design is generally incorrect. What you need is a straightforward `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT
    upvt.col1,
    upvt.col2,
    upvt.col3,
    upvt.ColName,
    upvt.Value
FROM table t
UNPIVOT ( Value FOR ColName IN
    (Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9)
) upvt
```

Comment: I have 3000 records in the original table, so should I write 3000 union all statements for 30 columns combination that I want to convert into rows ?, is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: No, you should unpivot into one column. I can give you a much simpler solution then

Comment: thanks, I can do unpivot into a single column but, I need the original column name tag with the value, so that I know which value belongs to which column. If I unpivot and put all values of all columns under 1 column, it wont help me to differentiate them.

Comment: Not sure you understand `UNPIVOT`, it **has** the column name, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0bee8/3/0

Comment: Got it, thank you. I misunderstood that you put all the values into 1 column as that is something that I already tried and I related to. I will try your SQL and get back to you tomorrow, but this should do. Many thanks all for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and then filter out the all-`NULL` values:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (col4, null, null), (null, col5, null), (null, null, col6)
     ) v(col4, col5, col6)
where v.col4 is not null or v.col5 is not null or v.col6 is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have thousands of records and around 50 columns in the original table that I want to convert. If I have to use values, it would be too many combinations/probabilities

Comment: @msv sounds like a bad design... there must be a better way...

Comment: @msv . . . It is 50 "combinations", one per column as you have phrased the question.

Comment: yeah it is a legacy table, I am trying to transform it for good and load it back to a new target

Answer (score 0):

In general there are two approaches (well, rather three):

1. Use a lot of typing to create a statement covering all your columns. This is ugly but fast. The biggest draw-back: Adding a column in the future will force you to re-do your queries.
2. Use a generic approach, which will work with any count of columns. The biggest draw-back: This won't be fast.
3. Dynamic SQL: Use Metadata to *create* the statement of suggestion 1. dynamically. The biggest draw-back: This will never work in ad-hoc/inline queries.

To show you one generic approach you might test this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(10),col2 VARCHAR(10),col3 VARCHAR(10),col4 INT,col5 INT,col6 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('a','b','c',NULL,500,200)
,('w','x','y',1000,300,NULL)    
,('z','g','h',200,NULL,600);
```

--The generic unpivot query

```
SELECT t.col1,col2,col3
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY B.attr) AS GroupIndex
        ,B.attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') ColumnName
        ,B.attr.value('.','int') ColumnValue
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT(SELECT t.* FOR XML RAW,TYPE)
            .query('<cols>{/row/@*[not(local-name()=("col1","col2","col3"))]}</cols>')) A(x)
CROSS APPLY A.x.nodes('/cols/@*') B(attr);
```

--This we can use within a `PIVOT` query

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT t.col1,col2,col3
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY B.attr) AS GroupIndex
          ,B.attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') ColumnName
          ,B.attr.value('.','int') ColumnValue
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT(SELECT t.* FOR XML RAW,TYPE)
                .query('<cols>{/row/@*[not(local-name()=("col1","col2","col3"))]}</cols>')) A(x)
    CROSS APPLY A.x.nodes('/cols/@*') B(attr)
) intermediateResult
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ColumnValue) FOR ColumnName IN(col4,col5,col6)
)p;
```

The idea in short:

- We use `APPLY` create an intermediate XML representation of your columns *behind* col1,col2 and col3. In order to achieve this, we first create a XML and use `query()` to return all columns except col1, col2, col3 as attributes in each row.
- We use XML's default to **omit** NULL values
- We add this as column `A.x` to the result set.
- Another `APPLY` will call the XML method `.nodes()`. This will add one row per existing attribute.
- The `intermediateResult` is an *unpivoted* set. **This is the format you should use for storage actually...**
- Now we can use `PIVOT` to get the output wanted.

The biggest advantage is, that you can add `col7` without any need to change this (in the generic part). The output-list of `PIVOT` will need any new column explicitly.

Comment: thanks for the options, the above query with simple unpivot worked for me.